# Change location of log file for "update-alternatives"

Tags: log, logging, update-alternatives

I am currently managing my logging system but while setting all log location a problem occured: I want to change the location of the file `/var/log/alternatives.log` and I have done some research. This file is part of `update-alterantives` which changes default programs like the editor, ruby and other programs. After reading the manual pages I found out that you can **set the log file with a parameter** but if the system starts the program, I cannot set this flag. I also didn't find a configuration file.

**How can I change the location of `/var/log/alternatives.log` permanently?**

Comment: Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I did this:
checked `echo $PATH` for a folder before `/usr/sbin/update-alternatives`
created a script in `/usr/local/bin` called `update-alternatives` containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Workaround to get "update-alternatives" to log to /var/log/dpkg/update-alternatives.log
# place in $PATH before /usr/sbin/update-alternatives eg. /usr/local/bin/
exec /usr/bin/update-alternatives --log /var/log/dpkg/update-alternatives.log "$@"
exit 0
```

made it executable etc.

Comment: What is "etc."?